# Can't connect local WordPress to a remote MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, remote-access

I have a local WP which I want to connect to a remote database. Even though my connection parameters in `wp-config.php` are correct, I'm getting 'Error establishing a database connection'.

With `WP_DEBUG` enabled, I see this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2049): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) in /media/AMPP/nginx-root/projects/lepleco/http/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1490

When I try plain mysql connect from Terminal:

```
mysql -h [correct-host] -u [correct-username] -p[correct-password] [correct-db-name]
```

Again I get this error:

> ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

The only way I am able to connect is with the `--skip-secure-auth` flag:

```
mysql -h [correct-host] -u [correct-username] -p[correct-password] [correct-db-name] --skip-secure-auth
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to use this for my WordPress connection.

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your password?

According to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47846) dba stackexchange post the fact that you cannot connect is not a bug.

I think that if you change your MYSQL password for this user and then try to reconnect you should be alright.

Comment: Trevor thanks for your reply. Before asking I spent days trying to find a solution and I also saw the answer you gave the link to. Changing password for mysql user doesn't help, the problem still exists. I never said anything about a bug, I just want to connect to my database.